What is the difference between var = ({},) * 2 and var = ({}, {}) in python?
What is the difference between var = ({},) * 2 and var = ({}, {}) in python?
Both should aasign two empty dictionaries to the variable.
Please explain why the first one is shallow copy and the second is not.
The below code returns True.
dict_a, dict_b  = ({},) * 2

dict_a["anything"] = "whatever"

return dict_a == dict_b

While this one returns False.
dict_a, dict_b  = ({}, {},)

dict_a["anything"] = "whatever"

return dict_a == dict_b


Basically the same as this but with dicts instead of lists.

important to understand, the first one doesn't make a shallow copy, it doesn't make a copy at all. It is the same dict object

Adding to @juanpa.arrivillaga, there's really three types of "copy" in Python, aliasing (what's happening here, where it's roughly equivalent to assigning a pointer to another pointer in C, but they still point to the same thing), shallow copies (the only type the language supports directly on objects via syntax and methods, which copies the outer structure of a container, but makes aliases of its contents), and deep copies (which recursively copy to arbitrarily deep nesting, almost always via the copy.deepcopy function).

@ShadowRanger yes, you can call it aliasing, but I think that's needlessly complicating the mental model of what is going on in Python. There are objects, that can be referenced in many different ways (aliased, using your terminology). That is what is usually going on in the normal course of a program (assignment statements, adding objects to built in containers, passing objects as arguments etc). Then there are copies which create new objects with their own identity.

Having an idea like aliasing makes sense in a language like C, where an operation like x = y or f(x) will routinely involve memory copies, so the idea of "aliasing" adds something useful. In Python, I think it isn't parsimonious, although, it would be useful for explaining Python's semantics to someone who is used to, say, C++

I'm mostly coming at this from the POV of explaining Python to a newbie. IMO Python's semantics are really straightforward and simple, but there are a lot of tutorials out there geared towards languages like C++ which needlessly complicate things. What you are saying is definitely a correct way of explaining things, though

The *2 just passes the reference of the same dictionary into the two variables.
>>> dict_a, dict_b  = ({},) * 2
>>> dict_a
{}
>>> id(dict_a)
4297720960
>>> id(dict_b)
4297720960

While the second example, you create two distinct dictionaries.
>>> dict_a, dict_b  = ({}, {},)
>>> id(dict_a), id(dict_b)
(4297720960, 4299571520)


result = ({},) * 2

is equivalent to:
d1 = {}
t1 = (d1,) 
result = t1 * 2

There's only one dictionary in the tuple t1. When the tuple is doubled, the result contains two references to that same dictionary, it doesn't make a copy of the dictionary.
result = ({}, {})

is equivalent to
d1 = {}
d2 = {}
result = (d1, d2)

Now there are two original dictionaries, and we create a tuple containing references to each of them.
